# DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found in AIX, but works in Windows

Tags: java, java-8, aix

We are parsing `String` to `xmlDocument` by using below API in java.

```
Document m1(string val){ DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); return
factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new
StringReader(val))); }
```

This works fine over Windows as it gets the `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl` API, but in AIX 7.2 we are facing an error:

> Uncaught Throwable [javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError:
>   Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not
>   found] detected in thread [SiebelEventProcess Thread(114)]
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not
>   found     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Is your application running on Websphere Application Server? Which version has WAS?

Comment: @OP Please state the Java version you use (eg 14, 5, 6, 71, 8). As far as I know, 8 is the latest IBM-Java for AIX.